# How do i give roles to members on discord.js in V13?

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

so i am making a discord bot and i want to to be able to add and remove roles to players.
in Discord.js V12 this works:

```js
const role =
            message.mentions.roles.first() ||
            message.guild?.roles.cache.get(args[0]);
          const member =
            message.mentions.members?.first() ||
            message.guild?.members.cache.find((m) => m.user.tag === args[0]) ||
            message.mentions.roles.first();

          await member?.roles.add(role?.id).catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

This no longer works in V13:

```js
Property 'roles' does not exist on type 'Role | GuildMember'.
  Property 'roles' does not exist on type 'Role'.ts(2339)
```

**Do anyone please have an answer i have search google for a day now?**

Comment: It's pretty confusing because according to the docs, [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.0.1/class/GuildMember) clearly has a `roles` property. 

But to test it out, you could `console.log(typeof member)` to check the variable's type. 
Also what is the exact version you're currently using?

Answer (score 0):

Over here

```js
const member =message.mentions.members?.first() || message.guild?.members.cache.find((m) => m.user.tag === args[0]) ||
message.mentions.roles.first()
```

You allowed it to be a mentioned role. Considering you named the variable `member`, I would guess you wanted it to ONLY be a `GuildMember`. Removing that will stop the warning

```js
const member =message.mentions.members?.first() || message.guild?.members.cache.find((m) => m.user.tag === args[0])
```

You can also make it default to the message author

```js
const member = message.mentions.members?.first() || message.guild?.members.cache.find((m) => m.user.tag === args[0]) ||
message.member
```